# Are questions about the sensibility of a plot on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about the sensibility of a plot on-topic?

Like, if I asked about whether or not this plot makes sense:

> An average psychologist in our world, prescribes LSD for a patient that is contraindicated for LSD.

That's intended as a blatantly crazy example. Well, I could justify it, but that's outside the scope of this example/question...

Comment: The plot makes sense: to proscribe means to forbid, so....

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 - *twitch* ... Okay... Funny, but I'm gonna fix that? ... Yeah, I am...

Answer (score 5):

<sup>(Not being a major contributor here, I'm not 100% sure what the community deems is on-topic. But here is my stab at answering this. Please vote accordingly.)</sup>

What is on topic here is primarily *how* to write, not *what* to write. Thus a plot making sense or not is not generally on topic. If a plot makes sense, but the way it's written doesn't convey that sense, maybe we can help you fix it. We can provide tips on the kinds of things you might add or subtract to make the writing convey the idea.

What we don't generally do is evaluate the idea. To some degree that will happen as a by-product, but it isn't the primary goal and isn't on-topic on its own.

For some plot-related questions, the [World Building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) stack might be appropriate, but they have their own scope so they are not a dumping ground for any plot-related questions we might encounter.

Comment: Mod on both Writing and Worldbuilding here.  As this answer says, questions about *what to write* aren't on-topic here.  Over on Worldbuilding, questions about *plot* or *individual characters* are not on-topic, but questions about your story's environment (world) -- physical, exotic creatures, culture, languages, science, etc -- are.  See the Help Center there for more info.